# TypeError: type Column doesn't define __round__ method

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have my data looks like this:

```
+-------+-------+------+----------+
|book_id|user_id|rating|prediction|
+-------+-------+------+----------+
|    148|    588|     4|  3.953999|
|    148|  28767|     3| 2.5816362|
|    148|  41282|     3|  4.185532|
|    148|  18313|     4| 3.6297297|
|    148|  11272|     3| 3.0962112|
+-------+-------+------+----------+
```

I want to create a new column name 'pred_class' by rounding values in prediction column. I run this code:

```
results.withColumn('pred_class',round(results['prediction']))
```

It gave me error like this:

> TypeError: type Column doesn't define **round** method

Anyone can help me with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using the `round` function from base python on a spark *Column* object, which is not properly defined. Use the `round` function from `pyspark.sql.functions` instead:

```py
results = spark.createDataFrame([{'book_id': 148, 'user_id': 588, 'rating': 4, 'prediction': 3.953999}])

from pyspark.sql.functions import round   # import the method here
results.withColumn('pred_class',round(results['prediction'])).show()

+-------+----------+------+-------+----------+
|book_id|prediction|rating|user_id|pred_class|
+-------+----------+------+-------+----------+
|    148|  3.953999|     4|    588|       4.0|
+-------+----------+------+-------+----------+
```